# C - Handling events across processes

Tags: c, events

I'm trying to figure out how to set up an event that could be carried into a child process. I need this in order to calculate the time it took for the parent process to communicate with the child process. The code I've got is here: http://pastebin.com/euVfSNeg
The problem is that when the app2.exe calls app3.exe nothing happens, because the event doesn't get fired/listened (dont know which one is the case).
I need to figure this out ASAP as I've got to hand it in in a couple of hours.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1. You shouldn't post "I need this urgently". 2. You should always add the code to your question, not link to it.

Comment: I know, I'm just in a dodgy situation and have to figure this out right now.. Sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396) says:

> `lpEventAttributes` A pointer to a `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` structure. If
>   this parameter is NULL, **the handle cannot be inherited by child
>   processes**.
>
> A child process created by the CreateProcess function can inherit a
>   handle to an event object **if the lpEventAttributes parameter of
>   CreateEvent enabled inheritance**

And you're passing `NULL` as the first argument.